# C# Nest (ElasticSearch) searching in nested array

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to return list of results depening on nested array. This my model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

If one of pages contains given quote than I want to return whole book.My attemp so far:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Book>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Nested(n => n
                    .Path(p => p.Pages)
                    .Query(nq => nq
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.Pages.First().Content) 
                            .Query("lorem ipsum")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

It works only if quote is in the first page, otherwise it won't recognize my book.